# Chrome WebUSB API returns no device when using navigator.usb.getDevices()

Tags: javascript, webusb

I'm trying the new Chrome WebUSB API, but can't see any connected device.

Tried this for example, with different USB devices connected to my Windows 7 PC:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                console.log('Clicked');
                navigator.usb.getDevices()
                  .then(devices => {
                    devices.map(device => {
                      console.log('Device:');
                      console.log(device.productName);
                      console.log(device.manufacturerName);
                    });
                  });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But got no device.

What am I doing wrong?
Should it work with any device?

Answer (score 6):

Until your page has requested permission to access a device `navigator.usb.getDevices()` will return an empty list. Inside your `onclick` handler call `navigator.usb.requestDevice()` instead with a filter selecting the vendor and product IDs of the devices you would like to support. See the example [from the specification](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/#dom-usb-requestdevice):

```
let button = document.getElementById('request-device');
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  let device;
  try {
    device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{
        vendorId: 0xABCD,
        classCode: 0xFF, // vendor-specific
        protocolCode: 0x01
    }]});
  } catch () {
    // No device was selected.
  }

  if (device !== undefined) {
    // Add |device| to the UI.
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it threw an exception. Is this answer outdated? the spec has this code:

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  let devices = await navigator.usb.getDevices();
  devices.forEach(device => {
    // Add |device| to the UI.
  });
});

I don't get a permission request, just an empty list no matter what I try.